# Make sure resource is applied last

Tags: terraform, resources, lifecycle

In terraform is there a way to make sure a specific resource is applied last, after all other resources have been applied?
Basically I need to execute local provisioner via `null_resource` after all other resources have been created. I know I can use `depends_on` to wait for specific resourced to be created, the problem is - there are too many of those other resources - so `depends_on` becomes bloated, also new resources may be added in the future, and I will have to remember to update `depends_on` every time.

Comment: No at the moment there is no such an easy option, yes `depends_on` can "do it" but like you mentioned there is not guarantee that as you add new resources the  depends_on your dependencies will become obsolete ... if you absolutely need this, you might want  to split your terraform project into two projects and have those resource you need last to run after

Comment: `null_resource` suggests that it's not a job for Terraform actually. Maybe all you need is run the thing directly from bash after Terraform finishes?

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy The issue is this terraform is triggered by different scripts in different scenarios. Having that particular provisioner inside `null_resource` would make it consistent central point of execution. I can have it run directly from bash (which, indeed I may have to), but then I have to copy this command to every script that executes terraform, and if at some point this terraform is applied outside of known scripts - this code won't be executed.